# svn: PUT 403 Forbidden on commit

Tags: svn, configuration, http

I have a new repository on a new server that uses CentOS and has CPanel for management. Getting SVN to work with CPanel was a pain but now it works ok, I can create repositories, I can checkout and I can see the repositories in browser. I can even commit if I try from command line, on the server, as root. The problem is that on my local working copy I get the following error when I try to commit.

svn: Commit failed (details follow):
svn: PUT of '/svn/testrepo/!svn/wrk/a9b6652a-2f01-0010-83aa-f9ff957523f6/index.php': 403 Forbidden

The repository is owned by the apache user and it has the right permissions. I've googled it for a while now and from what I can tell there is some Allow/Deny directive in the CPanel generated apache config that generates the 403 error.

The repositories are at
/home/repos/
And I access them by:
http://site.com/svn/repository

So /home/repos/testrepo should match http://site.com/svn/stestrepo

EDIT:
The logs look something like http://pastebin.com/cDkHMgrN

Comment: What do apache's logs say about the request?

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it concerns the use of shared web hosting by end users or resellers, rather than the administration of web hosting.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem was indeed related to the Allow/Deny directives ( I suppose CPanel has something to do with it).

After trying several configurations I added:

```
Order allow,deny
Allow from all
```

right after *SVNParentPath* in the svn apache config.

That did the trick!